# get error with using php nusoap for web service

Tags: php, web-services

i want get data from a webserver (.net) and display it into my website.

my code is :

```
$client = new soapclient('http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublic.asmx?WSDL', true);
$client->useHTTPPersistentConnection(); 

$user = array('UserName' => 'etc');
$pass = array('Password' => 'etc');

$result = $client->call('Board', $user, $pass);

print_r( $result );
```

and i get this error :

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset
> or empty in
> /home/mmdicir/public_html/lib/nusoap-0.7.3/lib/nusoap.php
> on line 7211
>
> Array ( [faultcode] =>
> soap:Server [faultstring] => Server
> was unable to process request. --->
> String reference not set to an
> instance of a String. Parameter name:
> s [detail] => )

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new soapclient('http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublic.asmx?WSDL', true);
$client->useHTTPPersistentConnection(); 

$user = array('UserName' => 'etc', 'Password' => 'etc'); use like this its will work
//$pass = array('Password' => 'etc'); // wrong

$result = $client->call('Board', $user, $pass);

print_r( $result );
```

Comment: Please add more info about why is wrong, not only mark/change it.